# Composer shows conflict between 2 compatible packages (original)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have an error trying to `composer install` my dependencies. Same error with `composer update`.

It says there's a conflict between symfony/web-server-bundle 4.3.3 and symfony 3.4 but those packages are supposed to be compatible:

- https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle/blob/4.3/composer.json
- https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/web-server-bundle

Here is my console output:

```sh
$ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
Deprecation warning: Your package name theredled/. is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
Deprecation warning: require.beberlei/DoctrineExtensions is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use beberlei/doctrineextensions instead. Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.4.30 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.30].
    - don't install symfony/web-server-bundle v4.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.30
    - Installation request for symfony/web-server-bundle v4.3.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/web-server-bundle[v4.3.3].
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "theredled/.",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
          "psr-4": {
              "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
          }
      },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.9",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~3.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~3.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.1",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "spe/filesize-extension-bundle": "~1.0.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.1",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.5",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.5",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.8",
        "debesha/doctrine-hydration-profiler-bundle": "^1.3",
        "xmon/color-picker-type-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/console": "~3.4",
        "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^7.4",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
        "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^2.1",
        "cocur/slugify": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.3",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.3",
        "onurb/doctrine-yuml-bundle": "1.1.5",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^6.1",
        "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.1.11"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: And what's the problem in this? symfony/web-server-bundle 4.3.3 requires symfony 3.4 (https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/web-server-bundle)

Comment: So no, it's not pretty clear for me.

Comment: Cool that you chose to close my question (?), but I still have no solution...

Comment: @yivi "You need to look deeper into the recursive dependencies" how can I do that?

Comment: And why do packagist.org say they are compatible?

Comment: Why can v3.4 of X and v4.3 of Y not be compatible? You can say that just by looking at the numbers? I don't get it.

Comment: Yet, packagist says `symfony/web-server-bundle` v4.3.3 requires: `symfony/console: ~3.4|~4.0`

Comment: composer says `The "--prefer-lowest" option does not exist.` :(

Comment: The `--prefer-lowest` flag only exists for `composer require|update`. I'd additionally suggest to update composer to the latest version with `composer self-update` before trying anything else.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich composer is up-to-date (1.9.0)

Comment: same problem with `composer update --prefer-lowest`

Comment: the fact is that even in the `composer.json` of those packages' githubs (such as https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle/blob/4.3/composer.json), is noted that `symfony/symfony` v3.4 is allowed. So my question is: why is there a conflict? how can I know where it is? what is the logic of it all?

Comment: I don't take it personnally, it's just that maybe you could have waited some comments from me, and made sure the question was wrong, before requesting a close.

Comment: What tools could I use to find the faulty package?

Comment: My bad, it's not installable. The problem are those two packages. Solution? Do not use incompatible versions.

Comment: I created a new 3.4 project and copying your `composer.json` (without the `scripts` section) everything installs as it should, `composer show` reports `symfony/symfony v.3.4.30` and `symfony/web-server-bundle v4.3.3`. Maybe remove the lock file and try to install?

Comment: @yivi but they ARE supposed to be compatible, just by looking at each of their `composer.json`.

Answer (score 7):

As I described it in [another answer recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57484992/2123530), you do get this error message because `symfony/symfony` acts as a replacement of `symfony/web-server-bundle` at its exact same version, because of this line: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/composer.json#L85

The composer documentation tells you exactly that and takes Symfony as an example to explain the `replace` section:

> This is also useful for packages that contain sub-packages, for
>   example the main symfony/symfony package contains all the Symfony
>   Components which are also available as individual packages. If you
>   require the main package it will automatically fulfill any requirement
>   of one of the individual components, since it replaces them.

*Source:* https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace

So with your `composer.json` as it stands, you are instructing composer to install `symfony/web-server-bundle` at the version `4.3.3` and to install `symfony/web-server-bundle` at the version `3.4.30` (via the request to install `symfony/symfony` at version `3.4.30`, that says it replace that package), and composer end up in an incompatible state, as explained by the error, to install a package at two different version at the same time.

```
- don't install symfony/web-server-bundle v4.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.30
- Installation request for symfony/web-server-bundle v4.3.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/web-server-bundle[v4.3.3].
```

=> *don't install `symfony/web-server-bundle`* is really what it means: you actually don't need it, it is part of `symfony/symfony` already

From here you have three options:

1. You remove the requirement for `symfony/web-server-bundle` in your `composer.json` (but that means you will have to live with that package at the version `3.4.30`, as provided by `symfony/symfony`)
2. You upgrade your `symfony/symfony` package to `4.3.3` (still leaving the requirement of `symfony/web-server-bundle` out of your `composer.json` because `symfony/symfony` does replace it).
3. You require the `symfony/*` package that you need one by one, but not via the "super-package" `symfony/symfony`.
   That's more work and more possible incompatibilities to deal with in a long term, but that is the only way to have `symfony/web-server-bundle` at version `^4.0` when still having other Symfony packages in versions `^3.0`.
   An example of that would be to replace this line of your `composer.json`:

   ```
   "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
   ```

   with

   ```
   "symfony/asset": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/browser-kit": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/cache": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/class-loader": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/config": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/console": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/css-selector": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/dependency-injection": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/debug": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/debug-bundle": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/dotenv": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/event-dispatcher": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/expression-language": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/filesystem": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/finder": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/form": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/framework-bundle": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/http-foundation": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/http-kernel": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/inflector": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/intl": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/ldap": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/lock": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/monolog-bridge": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/options-resolver": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/process": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/property-access": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/property-info": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/routing": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security-core": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security-csrf": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security-guard": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security-http": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/security-bundle": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/serializer": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/stopwatch": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/templating": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/translation": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/twig-bridge": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/twig-bundle": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/validator": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/var-dumper": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/web-link": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/workflow": "3.4.*",
   "symfony/yaml": "3.4.*"
   ```

   Which I just created by copying the [`replace` section of `symfony/symfony`'s `composer.json`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/composer.json#L36), where I replaced the `"self.version"` by your actual `symfony/symfony` version, and finally, removed the package `symfony/web-server-bundle`, since you require it on another version already.

As for your misunderstanding of the `composer.json` of `symfony/web-server-bundler`, this package is indeed compatibe with the packages of Symfony at version `^4.0` that are listed:

- symfony/config
- symfony/console
- symfony/dependency-injection
- symfony/http-kernel
- symfony/polyfill-ctype
- symfony/process

But ***not*** with the bundled "super-package" `symfony/symfony` that is indeed not present in the [require section of its `composer.json`](https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle/blob/4.3/composer.json#L18)